# Xamarin Forms: AbsoluteLayout

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, absolutelayout

I need to use an `AbsoluteLayout` for other controls on the page not listed here. How do I layout a common senerio where I have a `SearchBar` at the top, then a `ListView` which fills the rest of the screen.

I tried this, but the `ListView` goes incorrectly **under** the `SearchBar`

```
    <AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <SearchBar></SearchBar>
        <ListView 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1">
        </ListView>
      </AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: Using `StackLayout` will be more suitable for the scenario that you described.

Comment: I need an AbsoluteLayout for other reasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem is AbsoluteLayoutFlags you have set on the listview.

when you set it to all, you are telling the layout to start at 0,0 and go all the way to 1,1. Which is why the listview is appearing on the searchbar.

```
<AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <SearchBar AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,40"
               AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="WidthProportional,PositionProportional"/>
    <ListView 
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="XProportional,SizeProportional"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,40,1,1">
        <ListView.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                <x:String>mono</x:String>
                <x:String>monodroid</x:String>
                <x:String>monotouch</x:String>
                <x:String>monorail</x:String>
                <x:String>monodevelop</x:String>
                <x:String>monotone</x:String>
                <x:String>monopoly</x:String>
                <x:String>monomodal</x:String>
                <x:String>mononucleosis</x:String>
            </x:Array>
        </ListView.ItemsSource>
    </ListView>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

[Xamarin Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolute-layout#Proportional_Values)

I am sure you were referencing the documentation. I linked it here and quoting part of it. Hopefully it helps.

> Proportional values define a relationship between a layout and a view.
>   This relationship defines a child view's position or scale value as a
>   proportion of the corresponding value of the parent layout. These
>   values are expressed as doubles with values between 0 and 1.
>
> Proportional values are used to position and size views within the
>   layout. So, when a view's width is set as a proportion, the resultant
>   width value is the proportion multiplied by the AbsoluteLayout's
>   width. For example, with an AbsoluteLayout of width 500 and a view set
>   to have a proportional width of .5, the rendered width of the view
>   will be 250 (500 x .5).

Comment: Thank you @Neil, that was very helpful.